# Gaussian Regression using sklearn and GPFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am performing a Gaussian regression using Sklearn and GPFlow in Python. 
I noticed that I get very different outputs for the same kernel and the same inputs. I had to put a nugget for the sklearn kernel because otherwise the matrix is singular. 
Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Tensor Flow
import tensorflow as tf
import gpflow
from gpflow.utilities import print_summary

# sklearn
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor; from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF

train_x = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)[:,np.newaxis]
train_y = np.sin(train_x*2*np.pi)


eucl_temp = np.zeros((20,2))
eucl_temp[:,0] = train_x[:,0]
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
EUCL_DIST = pdist(eucl_temp, 'euclidean')
L_Kernel =  (np.mean(EUCL_DIST)/np.sqrt(2))

kernelRBF = gpflow.kernels.SquaredExponential(variance=1.0, lengthscale = L_Kernel)
m_BEFORE = gpflow.models.GPR(data=(train_x, train_y), kernel=kernelRBF, mean_function=None)
mean_Before, var = m_BEFORE.predict_y(train_x)

kernelRBF = RBF( L_Kernel )
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel= kernelRBF, optimizer = None, alpha = 1e-15).fit(train_x, train_y)
h = gpr.predict(train_x, return_std=False)
```

[image: GPR using sklearn and GPFlow]

The differences are quite huge. How come?

Answer (score 2):

I found out why. By default, the boise variance of the GPFlow model is 1. If I set the value lower, it is working.